# Generate .txt file and insert it into an oracle table pl / sql

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle-apex, utl-file

I have a procedure that receives the contents of a file in a single variable and I divide it into lines and divide the fields of each line delimited by commas, all that process I do it correctly but now I must generate a new file with some specific fields of the divided ones I have previously seen that all write files using utl_file write but I want to insert it in a table instead of an FTP server.
Is it possible to do this?
If yes, which is the best way to do it?

```
CREATE OR replace PROCEDURE process_file (filecontent CLOB) 
AS 
  contador NUMBER := 0; 
BEGIN 
    FOR i IN (SELECT Trim (column_value) l 
              FROM   dual, 
                     XMLTABLE ( ('"'|| replace (filecontent, '\r\n', '","')||'"'))) 
    LOOP 
        FOR i2 IN (select regexp_substr(i.l,'[^,]+',1) UNIDAD, 
        regexp_substr(i.l,'[^,]+',1,2) PERIODO, 
        regexp_substr(i.l,'[^,]+',1,3) COMPANIA, 
        regexp_substr(i.l,'[^,]+',1,4) ID_ORGANIZACION,
        regexp_substr(i.l,'[^,]+',1,5) ID_LIBRO_CONTABLE,
        regexp_substr(i.l,'[^,]+',1,6) ID_PERSONA_REG,
        regexp_substr(i.l,'[^,]+',1,7) NUMERO_EMPLEADO_REG,
        regexp_substr(i.l,'[^,]+',1,8) ID_PERSONA_DIS,
        regexp_substr(i.l,'[^,]+',1,9) NUMERO_EMPLEADO_DIS,
        regexp_substr(i.l,'[^,]+',1,10) ID_PERSONA_SUP,
        regexp_substr(i.l,'[^,]+',1,11) NUMERO_EMPLEADO_SUP,
        regexp_substr(i.l,'[^,]+',1,12) ID_PERSONA_GTE,
        regexp_substr(i.l,'[^,]+',1,13) NUMERO_EMPLEADO_GTE,
        regexp_substr(i.l,'[^,]+',1,14) NUMERO_EMPLEADO_CHEFF_GTE,
        regexp_substr(i.l,'[^,]+',1,15) COMENTARIOS,
        regexp_substr(i.l,'[^,]+',1,16) TIPO_SUPERVISOR,
        regexp_substr(i.l,'[^,]+',1,17) ID_PERSONA_CHEFF_GTE
        from dual) LOOP 
            IF(i2.UNIDAD = 'UNIDAD' 
               and i2.PERIODO = 'PERIODO' 
               and i2.COMPANIA = 'COMPANIA'
               and i2.ID_ORGANIZACION = 'ID_ORGANIZACION'
               and i2.ID_LIBRO_CONTABLE = 'ID_LIBRO_CONTABLE'
               and i2.ID_PERSONA_REG = 'ID_PERSONA_REG'
               and i2.NUMERO_EMPLEADO_REG = 'NUMERO_EMPLEADO_REG'
               and i2.ID_PERSONA_DIS = 'ID_PERSONA_DIS'
               and i2.NUMERO_EMPLEADO_DIS = 'NUMERO_EMPLEADO_DIS'
               and i2.ID_PERSONA_SUP = 'ID_PERSONA_SUP'
               and i2.NUMERO_EMPLEADO_SUP = 'NUMERO_EMPLEADO_SUP'
               and i2.ID_PERSONA_GTE = 'ID_PERSONA_GTE'
               and i2.NUMERO_EMPLEADO_GTE = 'NUMERO_EMPLEADO_GTE'
               and i2.NUMERO_EMPLEADO_CHEFF_GTE = 'NUMERO_EMPLEADO_CHEFF_GTE'
               and i2.COMENTARIOS = 'COMENTARIOS'
               and i2.TIPO_SUPERVISOR = 'TIPO_SUPERVISOR'
               and i2.ID_PERSONA_CHEFF_GTE = 'ID_PERSONA_CHEFF_GTE')THEN
            dbms_output.Put_line ('No se procesan los cabeceros');
            ELSE
            dbms_output.Put_line ('UNIDAD : ' 
                                  || i2.UNIDAD 
                                  || Chr (10)); 
            dbms_output.Put_line ('PERIODO : ' 
                                  || i2.PERIODO 
                                  || Chr (10)); 
            dbms_output.Put_line ('COMPANIA : ' 
                                  || i2.COMPANIA 
                                  || Chr (10)); 
            dbms_output.Put_line ('ID_ORGANIZACION : ' 
                                  || i2.ID_ORGANIZACION 
                                  || Chr (10));
            dbms_output.Put_line ('ID_LIBRO_CONTABLE : ' 
                                  || i2.ID_LIBRO_CONTABLE 
                                  || Chr (10));  
            dbms_output.Put_line ('ID_PERSONA_REG : ' 
                                  || i2.ID_PERSONA_REG 
                                  || Chr (10)); 
            dbms_output.Put_line ('NUMERO_EMPLEADO_REG : ' 
                                  || i2.NUMERO_EMPLEADO_REG 
                                  || Chr (10)); 
            dbms_output.Put_line ('ID_PERSONA_DIS : ' 
                                  || i2.ID_PERSONA_DIS 
                                  || Chr (10)); 
            dbms_output.Put_line ('NUMERO_EMPLEADO_DIS : ' 
                                  || i2.NUMERO_EMPLEADO_DIS 
                                  || Chr (10)); 
            dbms_output.Put_line ('ID_PERSONA_SUP : ' 
                                  || i2.ID_PERSONA_SUP 
                                  || Chr (10)); 
            dbms_output.Put_line ('NUMERO_EMPLEADO_SUP : ' 
                                  || i2.NUMERO_EMPLEADO_SUP 
                                  || Chr (10)); 
            dbms_output.Put_line ('ID_PERSONA_GTE : ' 
                                  || i2.ID_PERSONA_GTE 
                                  || Chr (10)); 
            dbms_output.Put_line ('NUMERO_EMPLEADO_GTE : ' 
                                  || i2.NUMERO_EMPLEADO_GTE 
                                  || Chr (10)); 
            dbms_output.Put_line ('NUMERO_EMPLEADO_CHEFF_GTE : ' 
                                  || i2.NUMERO_EMPLEADO_CHEFF_GTE 
                                  || Chr (10)); 
            dbms_output.Put_line ('COMENTARIOS : ' 
                                  || i2.COMENTARIOS 
                                  || Chr (10)); 
            dbms_output.Put_line ('TIPO_SUPERVISOR : ' 
                                  || i2.TIPO_SUPERVISOR 
                                  || Chr (10));
            dbms_output.Put_line ('ID_PERSONA_CHEFF_GTE : ' 
                                  || i2.ID_PERSONA_CHEFF_GTE 
                                  || Chr (10));
            dbms_output.Put_line ('***Termina línea***' 
                                  || Chr (10));
            END IF;          
        END LOOP; 
    END LOOP; 
END;
```

and to run:

```
DECLARE
    var_FILECONTENT   CLOB;
BEGIN
    var_FILECONTENT := 'UNIDAD,PERIODO,COMPANIA,ID_ORGANIZACION,ID_LIBRO_CONTABLE,ID_PERSONA_REG,NUMERO_EMPLEADO_REG,ID_PERSONA_DIS,NUMERO_EMPLEADO_DIS,ID_PERSONA_SUP,NUMERO_EMPLEADO_SUP,ID_PERSONA_GTE,NUMERO_EMPLEADO_GTE,NUMERO_EMPLEADO_CHEFF_GTE,COMENTARIOS,TIPO_SUPERVISOR,ID_PERSONA_CHEFF_GTE\r\n0101,42125,2525,300000001698016,78563,300000002861315,22,4855,e4730,155,e855,455,255,7525,Test_procedure,P,1525\r\n';

    TOKS_HCM_PROCESS_FILE (FILECONTENT => var_FILECONTENT);

END;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to insert it in a table

Why didn't you do that already? Instead of displaying values on the screen (using `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE`), use `INSERT` command. The rest of the procedure - if it works well - doesn't have to be modified.

Something like this (simplified):

```
CREATE OR replace PROCEDURE process_file (filecontent CLOB) 
AS 
  contador NUMBER := 0; 
BEGIN 
    FOR i IN (SELECT Trim (column_value) l 
              FROM   dual, 
                     XMLTABLE ( ('"'|| replace (filecontent, '\r\n', '","')||'"'))) 
    LOOP 
        FOR i2 IN (select regexp_substr(i.l,'[^,]+',1) UNIDAD, 
                          regexp_substr(i.l,'[^,]+',1,2) PERIODO, 
                          regexp_substr(i.l,'[^,]+',1,3) COMPANIA, ...
                    from dual
                   ) LOOP 
            IF(    i2.UNIDAD   = 'UNIDAD' 
               and i2.PERIODO  = 'PERIODO' 
               and i2.COMPANIA = 'COMPANIA' ...
              ) THEN
               dbms_output.Put_line ('No se procesan los cabeceros');
            ELSE
--> this is what you need
               insert into target_table(unidad, periodo, compania, ...)
                  values (i1.unidad, i2.periodo, i2.compania, ...);
--> end of what you need                  
            END IF;          
        END LOOP; 
    END LOOP; 
END;
```

Comment: hi @Littlefoot, I thought I had to do some more process to insert it as a file hehe it is the first time I use something like that but thanks I will go to complete my procedure